How potential energy is created in Electric dipole?
When an electric dipole is placed in electric field, it experiences a torque that tends to rotate it in the direction of the field. On the other hand, we say the potential $V$ is produced only when the work is done against the field ($\mathrm{d}V=-\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$). So, in case of dipole, how does it acquire potential energy without any work done?

There is an electric field setup by the dipole; the energies are in that.

The PE change comes from the change in the energy of the total field $\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}$. The energy density is $\tfrac12\epsilon_0(\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P})^2$. If we multiply this out we get $\tfrac12\epsilon_0E^2 + \tfrac12\epsilon_0P^2 + \epsilon_0(\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{P})$. As the dipole rotates relative to the field the magnitude of the dot product changes so the total energy changes.

@JohnRennie The electrostatic energy density is $\mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{E}/2$, not $\mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{D}/2$.

@VincentThacker $\mathbf{D} = \epsilon\mathbf{E}$. Yes?

I agree with the points made by John Rennie and Bob D. However, the conceptual difficulty may be due to the need to do work against the torque to rotate the dipole ($dV = -\tau \theta$).

I am confused by the specification that no work is being done. How is no work being done?

I noted that below

Sorry, I'm still not following. But if your question has been answered that's fine!

@JohnRennie Yes but also $\mathbf{D} = \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}$ and not $\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{P}$.

@VincentThacker Ah, oops, thanks :-)


So, in case of dipole, how does it acquire potential energy without
any work done?

An external agent needs to do work to rotate the dipole to be perpendicular to the field in order to acquire electrical potential energy.
Hope this helps.

Probably, the missing information is that, similarly to the case of a force's work, there is also work in the presence of an angular displacement in the presence of a torque (see, for instance, this Wikipedia page ).

Oh yes..I understand it

I understood the things that missing in the concept of potential energy from answers. The thing is represented in the fig. below. Whenever the dipole is placed in the Electric field, it experiences a torque force, that tends to rotate it along the field. So,

only if one  tries to rotate the dipole against the existing Electric
field, from its neutral position (A-B) to any other position (say
C-D), the work is done in the dipole and potential is created in it

The diagram that always (may be I seen) for 'potential energy of dipole' does not say about this information at a first glance (since only position C-D is noted without the transition from neutral position).
